# Javascript function for form created using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, slider

I have a script which adds a new form when a button is clicked to a HTML page with the code as following:

```
    <script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("Max number of forms, " + counter );
     }
     else 
    {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<form name='frmMain' action='prelucrare.php' method='POST'><div class='slot' id='dynamicInput' align='center'> Masina " + (counter +1 ) + "<table border='1'><tr><td align='right'><label for='marca'>Marca:</label></td><td colspan='2' align='left'>"
        + "<select id='marc' name='marc'><option selected value=''></option>"
    + "<tr><td align='right'><label for='motorizare1'> Motorizare:</label></td> <td><input type='range' name='motorizare1[]Input' min='0.6' max='5' step='0.1' value=2 id=motor1 oninput='outputUpdate1(value)'></td><td><output for=motorizare1 id=moto1>2</output></td></tr>"
        + "</div></form>"               
        ;
        }
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++; 
                                                } 
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Adauga" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

And I have the script bellow which changes the value from the slider.

```
<script>
    function outputUpdate1(mot1) {
                                document.querySelector('#moto1').innerHTML = mot1;
                                                }         
    </script>
```

My problem is that the JS code only changes the input for the first form, even if the slider is activated from another form. **In short, the slider should return the value in the form from which it is activate**; not only in the first form added. 
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're hard-coding the id `moto1` on every slider output: `<output for=motorizare1 id=moto1>`.  An id has to be unique, otherwise your selector will find the first element that has that id every time.  In your case, the first `moto1` id is in your first generated form

Comment: Thank you! And is there a solution for generating a different ID everytime a new form is displayed?

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).substring(10)`. I got this from another question on Stack Overflow. You will need to adjust the second number depending on the browser (Chrome yields 6-8 letters/numbers, IE 2-4, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going along with my comment, the problem is stemming from the id value being the same across all of your output elements (`moto1`).  You've actually got all the variables you need to make them unique since you're tracking a count of the number of forms on the page (your `counter` variable).  You can use this in place of your current output HTML:

```
    "<input type='range' name='motorizare1[]Input' min='0.6' max='5' step='0.1' value=2 id='motor_" + counter + "' oninput='outputUpdate1(value)'/>"
    "<output for=motorizare1 id='moto_" + counter + "'>"
```

You can update your function to parse out the correct index for the output you want to update since they should be in sync if you use the HTML above:

```
function outputUpdate1(mot) {
    // Get the counter part of the range element's id
    var index = mot.id.split('_')[1];
    document.querySelector('#moto_' + index).innerHTML = mot;
}
```

You may need to make some tweaks to code you haven't provided in the question, but that's one way of making the id values unique and how to access them without knowing the exact id ahead of time.

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea and I am trying to make it work. But it is still not working, I tried `alert ( index );` to check if it works, and no result. Normaly, the split method should result in index[0] = 'moto' and index[1] = counter.

Comment: In case a demo of splitting the index would help, you can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewm9dux3/)

Comment: Thank you @JonMichalik9, I used your code as inspiration for a new code, and it works very good. Thank you again. Here it is: `function changeId() {
  if (counter=="2") {
  document.getElementById("moto1").id = "id1";
  }
     if (counter=="3") {
  document.getElementById("moto1").id = "id2";
  }
  alert ( counter );
  }
function outputUpdate1(vot) {
  if (counter=="2") {
              document.querySelector('#id1').innerHTML = vot;
     }
  else if (counter=="3") {
     document.querySelector('#id2').innerHTML = vot;
     }
                                       }   `